# Get a KML layer from Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, kml, openlayers-2

Is there a way to export into KMl a geoserver layer?
I have used KML reflector but this doesnt return the whole content of the layer but a reference to it.
Alternatively can I get a KML of a layer using OpenLayers?

Comment: [Did you check the documentation?](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/KML-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.KML.write)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/googleearth/features/kmlreflector.html) a bit more carefully I found out there are different modes. 
In my case the "download" mode is what I am looking for.
From the documentation: *"Returns KML which contains the entire data set. In the case of a vector layer, this will include a series of KML placemarks. With raster layers, this will include a single KML ground overlay. This is the only mode that doesn’t dynamically request new data from the server, and thus is self-contained KML."*

So my request link looks like:

```
http://host:port/geoserver/wms/kml?layers=layer_name&mode=download
```

My problem is that some of the layers are not downloaded correctly and I get a KML file with:

```
      java.lang.NullPointerException null
```

while some other work great.

It seems like that the problem I mention was because of the styling of the layer. More specifically, the layers that would have problem to get downloaded as KMLs they had a style, which was assigned to a specific workspace (in geoserver). I have faced this problem in the past and the solution is to leave the choice: workspace (in style of layers) empty.